# How to persist jena data transactionally？

Tags: python, jena, fuseki

I use jena along with fuseki as my sparql server, and use python to perform HTTP request on sparql endpoint to insert/update. I need advice on how to make the process "transactionally" (I searched but didn't fully grasp this concept).

The configurations for the fuseki service are as below, which specifies dataset under directory tdb/. The service runs fine for a while. Then one day I found logs in my python project that shows querying fuseki endpoint failed. At the same time the Fuseki service reports

> org.apache.jena.dboe.DBOpEnvException: No known block type for 0

for all kinds of request. My web search results suggest that the cause might be that "A possible cause is that you used non-transactionally in the past and didn't flush changes to disk one time, or the app crashed".

Relevant web pages are:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201504.mbox/<5541034B.3000304@gmail.com>

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201603.mbox/%3C56F4412C.8010002@apache.org%3E

```
# Service Configuration

@prefix :      <http://base/#> .
@prefix tdb:   <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix tdb2:  <http://jena.apache.org/2016/tdb#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix ja:    <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix fuseki: <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .

<#serviceKgService>   a           fuseki:Service ;
fuseki:name                       "my_project" ;
fuseki:dataset                    <#dataset> ;
fuseki:serviceQuery               "query" , "sparql" ;
fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore      "get" ;
fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore "data" ;
fuseki:serviceUpdate              "update" ;
fuseki:serviceUpload              "upload" .

<#dataset> rdf:type ja:RDFDataset ;
ja:defaultGraph <#model_inf> .

<#model_inf> a ja:InfModel ;
ja:baseModel <#tdbGraph> ;
ja:reasoner [
ja:reasonerURL <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/GenericRuleReasoner> ; 
ja:rulesFrom <file:my_rules.ttl> ;
].

<#tdbGraph> rdf:type tdb2:GraphTDB ;
tdb2:dataset <#tdbDataset> .

<#tdbDataset> rdf:type tdb2:DatasetTDB ;
tdb2:location "tdb" .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;

# Rules
@prefix : <http://kg.example.com/kg_root#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

[transitiveRule: (?p :subLevelOf ?m), (?m :subLevelOf ?q) -> (?p :subLevelOf ?q)]


# Last Queries: I did some replacement, but the key points
# are 1. the first object value is a length-2 chineses string
# 2. the seconds object value is a length-50 english string
select distinct ?x where {
?x <http://kg.example.com/prop/direct/example_prop1> '示例'.
?x <http://kg.example.com/prop/direct/example_prop2> 'xxxxxxxx.xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxx_xxxx_xx'.
}

# Error

[2019-01-20 15:51:17] Fuseki     WARN  [5] RC = 500 : No known block type for 0
org.apache.jena.dboe.DBOpEnvException: No known block type for 0
at
org.apache.jena.dboe.base.block.BlockType.extract(BlockType.java:66)
```

Comment: Which version are you using? There was a problem like this but it was fixed at v3.7.0. The current version is 3.10.0

Comment: I use **3.9.0**

Comment: Is there anything that I can do (such as by reformatting HTTP request content in python or changing configuration in fuseki) to improve this?

Comment: I tried Jena 3.9.0 with the configuration given above and performed updates and queries.  This question needs a complete, minimal example - rules and initial data. (And the stacktrace,)

Comment: Hello, @AndyS I just added rules and last queries in the code region above. I did some minor changes on fix some value to be example, but the main characteristic remains unchanged.